# Why use a pointer when taking an array input in the parameter of a function

Tags: c, function, pointers

Why, in some cases, like in Leetcode, if a function wants to take an array input as a parameter, does it take a pointer and not like this "int arr[]"?  What is the reason for taking it as a pointer and what are the benefits of taking it as a pointer?

Why this one: `int (int *arr, int size)`?

Comment: It's always a pointer.  In a function parameter list, `int arr[]` is automatically converted to `int *arr`.

Comment: @user23118375, "... when taking an array input in the parameter of a function" --> invalid supposition.  A _parameter_ can not be an _array_.

Answer (score 3):

Parameters can't be arrays.

So we pass a pointer to the first element of the array (common)

```c
void f( size_t n, int *p ) {   // Sometimes written as `int p[]`.
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
      printf( "%d\n", p[i] );
   }
}

size_t n = ...;
int a[ n ] = { ... };
f( n, a );                     // Same as `f( n, &(a[0]) );`
```

or a pointer to the array itself (uncommon).

```c
void f( size_t n, int (*p)[ n ] ) {
   for ( size_t i = 0; i < n; ++i ) {
      printf( "%d\n", (*p)[i] );
   }
}

size_t n = ...;
int a[ n ] = { ... };
f( n, &a );
```

Note that `int p[]` as a parameter is just another way of writing `int *p`. They are 100% equivalent: a pointer to an `int`.

Comment: and why it pointes exactly at the first elemt of the array

Comment: Virtually every time an array is used (e.g. `f(a)`, `a[i]`, `p=a`, `a+i`, etc) , it degrades into a pointer to its first element. By definition. (Exceptions include `sizeof(a)` and `&a`)

Answer (score 0):

Arrays are weird.

Under most circumstances, array expressions "decay" to pointer expressions:

> **6.3.2.1 Lvalues, arrays, and function designators**
>
> ...
>
> 3 Except when it is the operand of the `sizeof` operator, or the unary `&` operator, or is a string literal
> used to initialize an array, an expression that has type "array of *type*" is converted to an expression
> with type "pointer to *type*" that points to the initial element of the array object and is not an lvalue.
> If the array object has `register` storage class, the behavior is undefined.

*[C 202x Working Draft](https://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n2310.pdf)*

In plain English, whenever you call a function with an array expression as an argument:

```
int arr[N];
...
foo( arr );
```

that expression is implicitly converted to something equivalent to

```
foo( &arr[0] );
```

and what your function actually receives is a pointer to the first element of the array, not a copy of the array.

Similarly,

```
int *p = arr; // equivalent to writing &arr[0]
```

Since the expression `arr` isn't the operand of the `sizeof` or unary `&` operators, it is converted from type "array of `int`" to "pointer to `int`" and its value is the address of the first element of the array.

In short, array expressions lose their "array-ness" under most circumstances and what you're actually dealing with is a pointer.  Among other things, this means you cannot pass arrays "by value" to functions.

Because of that conversion, we have this rule:

> **6.7.6.3 Function declarators (including prototypes)**
>
> ...
>
> 7 A declaration of a parameter as "array of *type*" shall be adjusted to "qualified pointer to *type*", where
> the type qualifiers (if any) are those specified within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation. If the
> keyword `static` also appears within the `[` and `]` of the array type derivation, then for each call to
> the function, the value of the corresponding actual argument shall provide access to the first element
> of an array with at least as many elements as specified by the size expression.

In the context of a function parameter declaration, `T a[N]` and `T a[]` are all interpreted to mean `T *a`; the argument is always a pointer, not an array.

If your function prototype is written

```
void foo( int a[N] ) { ... } // or int a[]
```

it will be interpreted as

```
void foo( int *a ) { ... }
```

Since all your function receives is a pointer to the first element, it has no idea how big the array is.  You can't use the `sizeof` trick

```
size_t count = sizeof a / sizeof a[0];
```

because `sizeof a` gives you the size of the *pointer*, not the entire array.  This is why you have to pass the number of elements in the array as a separate parameter:

```
foo( arr, N );
...
void foo( int *arr, size_t size ) { ... }
```

There *is* a reason for this behavior; it's not there just to confuse you. It's a bit beyond the scope of this answer, though, so I suggest you read [this paper](https://www.bell-labs.com/usr/dmr/www/chist.html) if you want to know more.